# I have a 50 amp plug into my panel. How many watts can I push into it from a generator?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, generator

I have a 50amp into my panel that has a built-in manual transfer switch for a generator. I want to buy a generator to hook into it.

If I am correct, the max Wattage I can push in would be 240V x 50 amps = 12kW. This means I should buy a generator that can feed 12kW (or perhaps slightly more to be comfortable) as buying a 20kW generator would be a waste of 8kW power.

Am I correct in this assumption?

Thank you!

Comment: Depends. If you think you need much more (rarely the case if you can apply a bit of common sense when on generator) the cost of direct-wiring a larger generator is trivial if the transfer switch can take more than the plug rating, and if  it can't, the cost of a larger transfer switch is not that much against the cost of the generator itself, unless you are buying junk-quality generators. You'd need new wire and breaker as well, of course, but that's peanuts against the cost of doing it at all.

Comment: I agree with above comment. It's budget driven. There's a sweet spot in portable cost effectiveness from around 8 to 12 kW.  Above that you start spending so much that a standby has to be a consideration.

Comment: FYI you don’t get to load wires and breakers at 100% of their rating continuously but rather only at 80%. So a 50A inlet is actually only good for 9600W continuous, but can go up to 12kW for shorter transients (like starting large motors).

Answer (score 1):

In practice you should aim to not use at more than 80% of it's rating. Not to satisfy the 3 hour continuous full current rating of the circuit, but because running near peak is hard on equipment. If you want to behave like you are still connected to utility to keep your generator from brown outs it is better to recognize your 50A breaker in your panel will pass 1.5x it's rating for two to five minutes before tripping, so 18kw peak (+/- 15kw running) rating of the generator. You can find portable generators in that range, starting at $3000 that are marginally portable, loud, and use lots of fuel.

That may be more than you need. The questions are do you have special needs that require you to use electric heat, electric hot water, do you need to do laundry, will you need to bake in an electric oven, and are you on a well?  If your answer to these questions are no then you really should ask yourself if you really need a big generator? Your your 50A inlet have have been provisioned for a 7500w or 9000w generator.

Real life considerations at my previous house I could answer no to all those questions lived in the city with buried power, gas appliances. Outages were generally short. I got by with a little 3200 watt generator. Quiet, efficient, easy to move, no need to maintain electric starting battery. But now I live in the woods, everything is electric. Power goes out, I initially assume it's going to be short duration, I turn off breakers for all the 240v loads and freezers and fire up the small generator and the wood stove. If I will need the well or ductless air conditioner I unplug the small generator and plug in a 5500w. That lets me run one 240v appliance (or clothes washing machine) at a time. I get by with the 5500w because that's what I have, but if it fails I will probable go with a 7500 or 9000 so I can run two or three 240v loads at a time.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of practical considerations in choosing a generator but just to address your question about one compatible with the inlet you already have.

First of all make sure the cable from the panel to the inlet is #6 and not any smaller.

Second, yes, you'll be feeding through a single 50 amp breaker so that is the max power you can feed.

But you can buy a slightly larger generator.  About 25% larger in a dual fuel one will allow you to run at your max capacity of 50 amps on natural gas.(The label rating is for gasoline.)  And a little larger than that  will reduce brownouts when running at high load.

Again. Practical considerations.  Weight, size, fuel consumption, cost etc.   Generators burn more fuel under high load so if you're planning to run air conditioners or an electric cooker off it, a natural gas hookup is mandatory. A 50 amp generator running continuously at capacity on gasoline is impractical.

And ... Good luck finding a dual fuel generator in the 15 to 18 kilowatt range. I think maybe there's one and its price is insane. And these things weigh like 500 lb which stretches the idea of portable.

Comment: Diesel is best in terms of fuel consumption at partial load - gasoline and NG both burn far more fuel just to keep the motor running at less than full load .vs. diesel fuel use following load pretty well from 25-100% loading.

Comment: Portable is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Ecnerwal The question says "plug" which I interpret as inlet, and MTF so I deduce portable.  If it's not portable, those things are irrelevant, you would just rip them out.  I've never considered diesel for residential but I suppose if you have a diesel vehicle and can run your own fuel cycling program that might be an approach. I don't know anything about those generators though.

Comment: Diesel is also **vastly** more expensive (like $5000 for 5kW vs $800 for 5kW gas). Perhaps worth it if you need to be able to run at high load for extended periods of time, but a lot of extra expense if you don’t.

Comment: @nobody Dinner at a proper steak house is **vastly** more expensive than a Little Caesers pizza for the same number of calories.   You're comparing a Kubota tier generator to a cheap-ass Amazon generator that won't last a season and is unrepairable because there is no parts support.  A more appropriate gas comparison is a Honda EB5000 at $2600.

Comment: I think a better restaurant analogy to getting a diesel generator for a budget-conscious residential project would be going to Best Buy for dinner.

Answer (score 0):

From a practical perspective, I had this same scenario and ended up going with an 18kw Powerhorse generator.  It has the 50 amp outlet on it.  It's portable, but also heavy; you'll need two beefy individuals to put it in a pickup truck.  I can run our smaller a/c unit (3.5 ton if I remember correctly) with it but not the main unit.  It is gas, but for me it just made the most sense cost and functionality wise.